# Counting the elements inside a list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists as follows

```py
[
 ['DDX11L1', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 11869, 14409],
 ['WASH7P', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 14404, 29570],
 ['MIR1302-2HG', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 29554, 31109],
 ['FAM138A', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 34554, 36081],
 ['OR4G4P', 'unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 52473, 53312],
 ['DDX11L1', 'transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 11869, 14409],
 ['WASH7P', 'lincRNA', 'chr2', 14404, 29570],
 ['MIR1302-2HG', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 29554, 31109],
 ['FAM138A', 'lincRNA', 'chr3', 34554, 36081],
 ['OR4G4P', 'unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 52473, 53312]
]
```

Inside lists `'chr'` will get differs as `'chr1'`, `'chr2'` and `'chrs'`. Depend on that chr, I want to count how many `'lincRNA'` are present.(not all the `'chrs'` will  have `'lincRNA'`)

Example answer:

I want to the result as follows:

```
There are 5 'lincRNA' with 'chr1'
There are 1 'lincRNA' with 'chr2'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your code? Sounds like a standard `Counter` implementation

Comment: Actually there are many more `'lincRNA'` with `'chr1'`.

Comment: @Austin Sorry i was giving the format of answer. Not the exact values

Comment: Ok, please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the number of each 'chrX' separately, a default dictionary will work nicely:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(int)

for ele in lst:
    if ele[1] == 'lincRNA':
        count[ele[2]] += 1

for k, v in count.items():
    print("There are {} 'lincRNA' with '{}'".format(v, k))
```

The result is as expected:

```
There are 1 'lincRNA' with 'chr3'
There are 1 'lincRNA' with 'chr2'
There are 5 'lincRNA' with 'chr1'
```

Comment: Although it solves the problem with given list in question, it will fail if index of `lincRNA` and `chrX` is different in inner lists.

Comment: It's consistent with the sample data in the question, unless stated otherwise we have no reason to believe that `lincRNA` and `chrX` can appear in different positions.

Comment: That is not an general answer, that is answer for only given list.

Answer (score 0):

That is fairly easy to do.  You have to do some for loops like this:

```py
for i in list:
    for b in i:
        print(str(b) + " " str(i))
```

This should access every item in every sublist.  Now you need to count with some if blocks:

```py
if b == "lincRNA":
    count_lincRNA += 1
```

You can do the same for every item you want to be counted.  After the for loop has finished you can print (or whatever) both counter variables

Another approach (as this would fail if there is trailing white spaces on the string "lincRNA") is to use RegEx, but I will leave that to you.

Comment: I think you need to read this part of the question again: *"I want to the result as follows:"*.

Comment: I'm afraid this post doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code also works fine when lincRNA isn't second element of any sublist and when there is more than one linRNA in any sublist.

```
my_list = [
 ['DDX11L1', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 11869, 14409],
 ['WASH7P', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 14404, 29570],
 ['MIR1302-2HG', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 29554, 31109],
 ['FAM138A', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 34554, 36081],
 ['OR4G4P', 'unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 52473, 53312],
 ['DDX11L1', 'transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 11869, 14409],
 ['WASH7P', 'lincRNA', 'chr2', 14404, 29570],
 ['MIR1302-2HG', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 29554, 31109],
 ['FAM138A', 'lincRNA', 'chr3', 34554, 36081],
 ['OR4G4P', 'unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 52473, 53312]
]
chrs = ["chr1","chr2","chr3"]
output = {"chr1":0,"chr2":0,"chr3":0}
for l in my_list:
    for _chr in chrs:
        if l.count(_chr) > 0:
            output[_chr] += l.count("lincRNA")
for k,v in output.items():
    print("There are {} 'lincRNA' with {}".format(v,k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using dict

```
store = {}

L = [['DDX11L1', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 11869, 14409], 
['WASH7P', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 14404, 29570], 
['MIR1302-2HG', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 29554, 31109], 
['FAM138A', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 34554, 36081], 
['OR4G4P', 'unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 52473, 53312], 
['DDX11L1', 'transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 11869, 14409], 
['WASH7P', 'lincRNA', 'chr2', 14404, 29570], 
['MIR1302-2HG', 'lincRNA', 'chr1', 29554, 31109], 
['FAM138A', 'lincRNA', 'chr3', 34554, 36081], 
['OR4G4P', 'unprocessed_pseudogene', 'chr2', 52473, 53312]]

if L:
    for rec in L:
        if rec[1] == "lincRNA":
            if rec[2] in store:
                store[rec[2]] = store[rec[2]] + 1
            else:
                store[rec[2]] = 1

for key, value in store.items():
    print("There are '{0}' linkRNA with '{1}'".format(value, key))
```