# calculating entropy and information gain python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decision-tree, entropy, information-gain

I'm a beginner in python trying to calculate entropy and information gain without using any libraries. Calculation results matter more than code quality right now.

I have the data frame and want to make lists of attribute count like this

```
Outlook = [
    [4, 0],  # overcast
    [2, 3],  # sunny
    [3, 2]   # rain
]
temperature = [
    [2, 2],  # hot
    [3, 1],  # cool
    [4, 2]   # mild
]
```

This is my data :
[play golf data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFi3p.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I don't understand what are those coordinates or how would you get there.  I don't know in what exactly is that data set in.  numpy? SQL? json?  And lastly I cannot see any code.

Comment: have u seen the data set image? i have no idea what to code . data set is in cvs file format . a very basic one.

Comment: Outlook = [
    [4, 0],  # overcast]   this means there are 4 instances of overcast against yes of attribute outlook and 0 instances of overcast against no of attribute outlook

Comment: You should start reading the docs about CSV: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html  I think you will find there examples that are pretty much similar to what you want todo.

Comment: could'nt find anything there . i have the cvs file in a data frame i now have to "count" attribute values

Comment: ..... is the data in a dataframe (numpy?) or in a CSV file?

Comment: does the below code converts cvs to numpy?import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['playgolf.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
df

Comment: please view code at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kBuhGWJiHMdaKW5U2vS3puht6hxJaFnp

Comment: You are close, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889796/counting-the-elements-inside-a-list-of-list/58889851?noredirect=1#comment104045700_58889851

Comment: ok thanks, i am gonna try that